# Tensorflow code runs with GPU in terminal, while Pycharm can't detect it with same Python interpreter

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm, gpu

I followed Tensorflow official [instructions](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip?hl=it) for its installation. If I run Tensorflow code from terminal with:
`python filename.py`
Tensorflow will detect and use GPU.
If I run the same filename.py in PyCharm, with the same Python interpreter as the terminal one, I get the warning:
`tensorflow/tsl/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:28] Could not find cuda drivers on your machine, GPU will not be used.`

I thought the problem was the virtual environment, but even if I use the system interpreter it stays the same. I have two system PATH variables for nvidia and cuda and I copied them both on Pycharm > Appearance & Behavior > Path variables.
Thanks in advance for the help.